# Get reference to object from base class. Decorator design pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, composition

Im dealing with [Decorator design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator). What i got now:

My Base `abstract class Worker`:

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    public float UsdPerHour { get; set; }
    public int HoursPerDay { get; set; }
    public int DaysOfWork { get; set; }

    public abstract float CountSalary();
}
```

Its abstract, because its base for my `Workers` classes. i think its not necesery, what is inside that classes. If you want to, i will add it to my edit.

Next i start implementing my decorator. Each `Worker` have `CountSalary()`. I want to applying bonuses to their salary based on decorator.

We are starting on `abstract Bonus` class:

```
public abstract class Bonus : Worker
{
    public Bonus(Worker worker) => this.worker = worker;
    public override float CountSalary() => worker.CountSalary();

    private Worker worker { get; set; }
}
```

Bonus are base clas for `AmountBonus` class.

```
public class AmountBonus : Bonus
{
    public AmountBonus(Worker worker) : base(worker: worker){ }
    // is this 'base' call correct?

    public override float CountSalary()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Worker worker;
}
```

My question is, how to get reference to object `Worker worker` in base class (`Bonus`) in concrete decorator class as `AmountBonus`?

**EDIT**

Based on your help, can i delete `private Worker worker` from `AmountBonus` class, and play with `worker` from base `Bonus` class like `base.worker`? Is it possible?

[image]

VS didnt tells me, that is not allowed

```
public override float CountSalary() => base.worker.CountSalary();
```

Comment: Currently you cannot get access to your `Worker worker` because it is `private`. If you want to access it from a base class use `protected` instead then you can use `worker` or if that's ambiguous `base.worker`

Comment: Although, let me check my info. Didn't notice your "Bonus" class was abstract

Comment: Thats true. Bonus is an `abstract`

Comment: You probably want `protected Worker worker { get; private set; }`, this way only the `Bonus` type can assign to this property, but descendants can read from it.

Comment: Yup, it works. Even IntelliSense shows it now https://imgur.com/a/PkXExYX

Comment: I Make edit to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By turning your `private Worker worker { get; set; }` into `protected Worker worker { get; set; }` classes outside cannot access it, but base classes can. This works even if the base class is `abstract`

**Edit:** This would also be a good time to learn about C# naming conventions ;)  [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)
**Edit 2:** As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089322/get-reference-to-object-from-base-class-decorator-design-pattern#comment95011405_54089322) comment points out, you probably want to use a `private set` with your `Worker worker`

**Edit after question Edit:** You still (only if you want) need the Worker in the `Bonus` class but you do not need to declare `private Worker worker;` again, as this (correctly pointed out by intellisense) hides the `Bonus.worker` worker. If the `Bonus.Worker` is set to protected, and not private, you can use it from your inherited classes without having to declare it again. This would be the result:

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    public float UsdPerHour { get; set; }
    public int HoursPerDay { get; set; }
    public int DaysOfWork { get; set; }

    public abstract float CountSalary();
}

public abstract class Bonus : Worker
{
    public Bonus(Worker worker) => this.worker = worker;
    public override float CountSalary() => worker.CountSalary();

    protected Worker worker { get; private set; }
}

public class AmountBonus : Bonus
{
    public AmountBonus(Worker worker) : base(worker: worker){ }

    public override float CountSalary()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer